# PHP : Cannot assign an Object to array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have create the following class :

**Main class file**

```
class NativeTabs
{
    private $tabs = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once('/options_elements.php');
    }

    public function add_tab($key = '', $name = '')
    {
        // ...

        $this->tabs[$key] = $name;
        $this->tabs[$key][] = new OptionsElements();

        // ...

    }
}

$nt = new NativeTabs();
$nt->add_tab('tabname', "Tab Name");
```

**options_elements.php File**

```
class OptionsElements
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

And when I execute that code I get the following error :

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in PATH/TO/MY/FILEnative_tabs.php on line THE_LINE_THAT_CONTAIN_THE_CODE($this->tabs[$key][] = new OptionsElements();)

Why I can't assing the object in `$this->tabs[$key][]` ?

Any idea please ?

Comment: `$this->tabs[$key]` references a String, not an Array.

Comment: Oh now i see !!! I am so shy :(

Comment: Why you put `require_once` statement in `NativeTabs` constructor?

Comment: And why not ? Is that bad ? :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
$this->tabs[$key] = array();
 $this->tabs[$key][] = new OptionsElements();
```

otherwise you use [] with a string (you assigned `$this->tabs[$key] = $name;` on the line above so `$this->tabs[$key]` is a string)

Answer (score 2):

`$this->tabs[$key]` is a **string**, not an array.

You can't add an item to a string as if it was an array.

Answer (score 1):

Why should you be able to assign that?

```
$this->tabs[$key] = $name;
```

Judging by the name you just set the array element to a string. Then you try to append an array element to this string? That won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This will work without errors.

```
$this->tabs[$key] = array("name");
$this->tabs[$key][] = new OptionsElements();
```

Answer (score 1):

See inline.

```
$this->tabs[$key] = $name;
// $this->tabs[$key] becomes a string that contains $name
$this->tabs[$key][] = new OptionsElements();
// $this->tabs[$key][] has no meaning here as its neither array nor an unset value. 
// if it was unset or not declared PHP would have make it an array.
```

You could you the following.

```
$this->tabs[$key]['name'] = $name;
$this->tabs[$key]['option_elements'] = new OptionsElements();
```